# Shell-script on-off Feature

Tags: shell-script

I want to make shell-script that have on and off feature
Just like this
First time:

```
echo -e "Activated!"
```

Second time:

```
echo -e "Deactivated!"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Pseudo code: `if something_is_turned_on; then turn off; else turn on; fi`

Comment: Example on how to know the state: On the first run, `touch` a file. On the second one, `rm` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this mean you would have to save the current state of the activation.

The easiest way to do this would be to create a file for one of the states (maybe for the "on" or "activated" state), and to remove that file when entering the other state ("off" or "deactivated").

Creating an empty file is done with `touch filename`, and testing for existence of that file is done with `if [ -e filename ]; then ...; fi`.  Remove the file with `rm filename`.

The below gives you the option to store a bit of information in that state by saving the value of a variable to a file.  In this case, the state is carried by a persistent file that is changed each time you run the script (rather than just a file that is either created or removed with each invocation of your script).

Assuming you are using `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

statefile=$HOME/.script.state

if [ -f "$statefile" ]; then
    . "$statefile"
fi

case $state in
    on) state=off ;;
    *)  state=on
esac

printf 'Current state is "%s"\n' "$state"

declare -p state >"$statefile"
```

Testing:

```
$ bash script.sh
Current state is "on"
$ bash script.sh
Current state is "off"
$ bash script.sh
Current state is "on"
$ bash script.sh
Current state is "off"
```

The script saves the variable `state` to `$HOME/.script.state` by means of `declare -p state` in `bash` at the end of each run, and reads it from there by sourcing that file at the start (if the file exists).

This file would end up looking like

```
declare -- state="off"
```

which is the output of `declare -p state` if `$state` is the string `off`.

---

With `/bin/sh`, the above script may be written as

```sh
#!/bin/bash

statefile=$HOME/.script.state

if [ -f "$statefile" ]; then
    read state <"$statefile"
fi

case $state in
    on) state=off ;;
    *)  state=on
esac

printf 'Current state is "%s"\n' "$state"

printf '%s\n' "$state" >"$statefile"
```

... just replacing the reading and writing of the state with `read` and `printf`, which would save just the state string itself in the state file.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to invert state automatically at each run, you might also take advantage of the "logical negation" numeric operation, which is useful to invert a value. That is, the logical negation of 0 is 1, and vice versa.

POSIX shells are capable of performing the most common numeric and bitwise operations by means of [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04), and [Bash is no short](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic), providing also [Arrays](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Arrays) that can be indexed by an integer number like 0 or 1 (and more).

In practice:

```bash
(
# our persistent file to save state into
file=./state
# array of two states, "off" is the first so that it will be 0, and "on" will be 1
states=(off on)
# import what's been saved in our state file, if present
[ -f "$file" ] && source "$file"

# within the arithmetic expansion syntax,
# we compute new state as the logical negation (the `!` operator) of the current state
state=$(( !(state) ))
printf 'state=%d\n' $state > "$file"  # save new state to persistent file

# print current state from the array using the numeric state as index 
printf 'currently %s\n' "${states[state]}"
)
```

In a strictly POSIX shell it is a bit more complex because we need to work around the lack of arrays:

```bash
(
file=./state
# here we use a simple string instead of an array
states='off on'
[ -f "$file" ] && . "$file"  # the `source` command POSIXly is just `.`

state=$(( !(state) ))
printf 'state=%d\n' $state > "$file"

# here we use the `cut` tool to select the piece of string based on numeric state
echo -n 'currently '; printf '%s\n' "$states" | cut -d ' ' -f $((state+1))
)
```